# How to enable systemd unit to run at startup

Tags: systemd, systemd-unit

I have a service that processes items from a RabbitMQ queue, of which I spool additional instances as the queue grows in size. How can I enable systemd to start a single instance of the unit at startup?

Here's my unit file:

```
[Unit]
Description=A service (%i) to consume items from a queue
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/queue-consumer.sh start %i

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
systemctl enable <servicename>@<instancename>
```